# Get days between start and end date without weekend and + - span

Tags: r, date, timespan, weekend

now I have a new question. I need to calcualte the timespan between two dates. My problem is: Weekends have to be excluded and the timespan can be minus or plus.
For example:

```
Planed delivery Real delivery  
2017-11-28     2018-11-17  
2016-05-10     2016-09-22 
2016-06-08     2016-11-07   
2016-07-08     2016-06-07
```

and so on.
I have the following code to do that:

```
getDuration <- function(date_scheduled, date_received,fmt="%Y-%m-%d") {
    myDays <- ifelse(date_received > date_scheduled,
                    seq.Date(to   = as.Date(date_received, format=fmt), 
                       from = as.Date(date_scheduled, format =fmt), 
                       by   = 1),
                     seq.Date(to   = as.Date(date_scheduled, format=fmt), 
                        from = as.Date(date_received, format =fmt), 
                        by   = 1))
     length(myDays[!is.weekend(myDays)])
}
```

When I use the command:

```
getDataPart(prep_DPM_All_new$Goods_received_date, prep_DPM_All_new$Schedule_Line_Delivery)
```

I got the following error:

```
Error in seq.Date(to = as.Date(date_received, format = fmt), from = as.Date(date_scheduled,  :'from' must be of length 1
```

At first I thought that the date columns are not formatted in the right way, but it looks good i think.

```
str(prep_DPM_All_new$Goods_received_date)
 POSIXct[1:33078], format: "2016-03-24"  
str(prep_DPM_All_new$Schedule_Line_Delivery)
 POSIXct[1:33078], format: "2016-03-29"
```

Can anyone help me and explain, why I get the error?
Without the if else statement I got the error, that "wrong sign in by".

The output should be somethinig like this:

```
Row 1: 254  
Row 2: 109   
Row 3:  98   
Row 4: -24
```

I tried to solve the problem by using some solutions for similar problems, but those problems had only postive values. I think the negative values are the main problem.

Comment: what results do you expect from the table above?

Comment: Row 1: 254,   Row 2: 109, Row 3: 98, Row 4: -24

Comment: Please, can you double check the expected result. I believe the result for rows 2 and 3 has been exchanged.

Answer (score 0):

`seq.Date()` is somewhat tricky here for two reasons:

1. The function is not vectorized, i.e., only single valued parameters are allowed.
2. The `from`, `to`, and `by` arguments must correspond, i.e., if `to` is lower than `from` then `by`must be negative.

Here is a solution which groups by row number to overcome issue 1. and uses the `sign()` and `range()` functions to overcome issue 2. In addition, the `chron` package is used from which the OP has taken the `is.weekend()` function.

```
library(data.table)
library(chron)
# coerce to data.table and chron
DF <- setDT(DF)[, lapply(.SD, chron, format = "y-m-d")]
DF[, rn := .I][, {
  s <- sign(Actual_delivery - Planned_delivery)
  r <- range(Actual_delivery, Planned_delivery)
  .(diff.working.days = s * sum(!is.weekend(seq(r[1], r[2]))))
}, by = rn]
```

> ```
>    rn diff.working.days
> 1:  1               254
> 2:  2                98
> 3:  3               109
> 4:  4               -24
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DF <- fread(
  "Planned_delivery Actual_delivery  
2017-11-28     2018-11-17  
2016-05-10     2016-09-22 
2016-06-08     2016-11-07   
2016-07-08     2016-06-07"
)
```

Comment: Crazy solution! O.o Didn't thought that it is so complicated to do such an "easy" task. :/ Nevertheless, can you explain me, how the function works? I've never seen the "." in front of the the letters, (Ok, I'm also new in R) as well the declaration ":=" (whereas, I know it from another programming language).

Comment: All your questions can be answered studying the `data.table` way. this cheat sheet might help: https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/blog_assets/datatable_Cheat_Sheet_R.pdf

Comment: In R, you usually have different options to achieve the same result. This is `data.table` syntax which I do prefer for grouping. Please see the vignettes and FAQ on https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started.

Comment: Hallo again, I have a little new problem. When I try it, I have to use characters instead of date format for the columns. Is there the possibility to convert the Formular for date formats instead of characters? I have a few other formulars which have access on these date format columns. Torte :).